# React Native : WebSocket Sub Protocol

Tags: react-native

Facebook React Native provides [WebSocket](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) polyfills

How can I set the sub protocol?

I tried the following code and it does not work

`new WebSocket('http://url', 'wamp.2.json')`